# Solutions of homogeneous linear differential equation form a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, vector-spaces

> Show that the solutions of a homogeneous linear differential equation $y''+a(x)y'+b(x)y = 0$ form a vector space. What is its dimension?

I understand that the dimension is 2 and that 0 is a solution to the differential equation ($0''+a(x)*0'+b(x)*0=0$).

How does one go about proving the other two properties of a vector space: closed under addition and closed under multiplication?

Comment: Suppose that $y_1$ is a solution. Can you also show that $cy_1$ is a solution for any constant $c$? You've proved closure under scalar multiples.

Comment: Let $y_1,y_2$ to solutions, show that $y_1+y_2$ is a solution too, after that show that $\lambda y_1$ is a solution, where $\lambda\in\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: I understand what I need to prove, a constant times the solution and two solutions added together are both solutions as well.  However, I have to idea how to do this from a completely theoretical standpoint.  If I had hard numbers, that would be easy.  I have no idea how to show that $cy1$ is a solution to this equation.

Comment: Is this statement true if any one of boundary condition is mentioned, for example x(0) = 1?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let $y_1,y_2$ be solutions for the equation
$$y''+ay'+by=0.$$

Then
$$y_1''+ay_1'+by_1=0$$
$$y_2''+ay_2'+by_2=0$$
Add the first and the second equation we have
$$(y_1+y_2)''+a(y_1+y_2)'+b(y_1+y_2)=0.$$
Then $y_1+y_2$ is solution too.

Let $\lambda$ be a real number
$$\lambda y_1''+a\lambda y_1'+b\lambda y_1=\lambda(y_1''+ay_1'+by_1)=0.$$
Then $\lambda y_1$ is solution too.

Comment: That makes sense.  It clicked when I read this.  Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Is this statement true if any one of boundary condition is mentioned, for example x(0) = 1?

Comment: @Aziz In this case, we need the information about x'(0) too. Therefore, the solution is unique.

Answer (score 1):

Let $V = \{y \mid y'' + ay' + by = 0\}$.

To show that $V$ is closed under scalar multiplication, let $k \in \mathbb{R}$ and $y(x) \in V$. You want to show that $ky \in V$, so you need to verify that $ky$ satisfies the defining property of $V$; namely, you need to show that $(ky)'' + a(ky)' + b(ky) = 0$ by using that fact that $y \in V$, so $y'' + ay' + by = 0$.

Likewise, to show that $V$ is closed under vector addition, let $y_1, y_2 \in V$. You want to show that $y_1 + y_2 \in V$, so you need to verify that $y_1 + y_2$ satisfies the defining property of $V$; namely, you need to show that $(y_1 + y_2)'' + a(y_1+y_2)'+b(y_1+y_1) = 0$ by using the fact that $y_1, y_2 \in V$, so $y_1'' + ay_1' + by_1 = 0$ and $y_2'' + ay_2' + by_2 = 0$.

Comment: Is it true for non homogeneous differential equation that is will be a vector space? (If we assume that $V$= solution set + {0} )

Comment: @DeepakKumar: No. The set $V$ will not be closed under scalar multiplication or addition (I encourage you to verify this using the approach in my answer). However, without including $0$, the solution set will be an affine space. Namely $V = p + V_0$ where $p$ is any solution to the non-homogeneous differential equation, and $V_0$ is the vector space of solutions to the corresponding homogeneous differential equation.